# CSS Animation & ScrollToFixed w/ Bootstrap Accordian

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Two part question...

**First** – 
I've written a css animation but it's pretty jumpy and I was hoping someone would be able to help me improve it. If you go here... http://area51res.e-retailer.co.nz/estore/style/s42020.aspx and then click "Share".

Any suggestions or ideas on how I can improve it?

**Secondly** – On this same page I used the ScrollToFixed jquery plugin (https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed) however if you scroll to the bottom when it hits the Most Viewed products and click one of the accordian items in the product detail section (Shipping, Returns etc) then it buckles the content overlaps the Most Viewed products. I've tried to trigger an event with bootstrap collapse (shown.bs.collapse) and then run   $(window).resize(); but this then collapses the accordion item again. Any ideas how I can stop it doing this?

Cheers
Michael

Comment: Do you have a JSFiddle with some code I can play with?

Comment: try to give extra delay timer to transition.

Comment: Yep I'll make one up for you now